Optimizing Docker Image Storage and Cache Management in Self-Hosted Build Agents
I am facing a significant issue with my self-hosted build agents in my CI/CD pipeline, and I need a comprehensive solution. Here are the details:
Build Agents and Services
I have 6 build agents.
I manage 30-40 services in the pipeline.
Problem
During the build process, my self-hosted build agents' disks are becoming full due to the accumulation of Docker images and cache layers.
We are already using the scratch base image to minimize the size of the Docker images.
Requirements
I need a solution that can preserve the cache layers to speed up the build process but also ensures that the disk does not get full.
What I Tried and Expected Results
I have attempted several solutions to address the issue, but none have been entirely satisfactory:
Docker System Prune -a 


Command: docker system prune -a
Expected Outcome: Free up disk space by removing all unused data (containers, networks, images, and cache).
Actual Result: This solution significantly slowed down the build process as it removed essential cache layers.

Docker Image Removal in Azure Pipeline
Command:
bash: |
  docker rmi img/address/image_name:$(Build.BuildId)
displayName: "Docker Delete"


Expected Outcome: Remove specific images to free up space.
Actual Result: This command did not free up enough space to prevent the disk from becoming full.
Desired Solution
I need a solution that keeps the build process fast and prevents the disk from getting full. It is acceptable to delete images and containers if necessary.

Please provide a solution that addresses the following:

Maintaining Build Speed: Ensure that the build process remains efficient and quick.

Effective Disk Space Management: Implement a strategy to manage disk space effectively.

Preserving Cache Layers: Find a way to keep essential cache layers while freeing up disk space.

Automation and Maintenance: Utilize scripts or tools to automate the cleanup process without manual intervention.


Can you help with a solution that meets these requirements?

How big are the disks and how often do they get full? Do you have an idea on how many builds per day use Docker?

Hi @RuiJarimba,
We have a 500GB disk that gets full in 3-4 weeks, causing a blockage in our build pipeline.

Do any of the below answers help?


We have a 500GB disk that gets full in 3-4 weeks

As a starting point, and to keep it simple:

Create a pipeline to do a proper cleanup (running docker system prune -a) based on a schedule - let's say every day after office hours, or 1-2 times per week.

Consider also running the prune command without the -a more often, in order to remove all unused containers, networks, images (both dangling and unused).

You can also cache some Docker base images by pulling some (or all) of them in the same pipeline right after the cleanup.


Something like:
trigger: none

- cron: '0 0 * * SUN'
  displayName: Weekly Sunday build
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  always: true

steps:
  - bash: |
    docker system prune -a

    docker pull my-base-image-a
    docker pull my-base-image-b
    # other base images to pull here
  displayName: "Docker cleanup and pull images"
  retryCountOnTaskFailure: 3 # configure retries
  condition: always()

The minor disadvantage of this approach is that the first builds that run after the cleanup pipeline will take longer (in case you decide not to pull some/all base images in advance).
But, on the other hand, cached images might not be updated with the latest security patches. For this reason cache should be refreshed frequently.

You are using self-hosted agents and you should maintain your resources locally instead of from within the pipeline.
As a workaround, you can create a separate pipeline to remove all unused images and stopped containers and configure schedules for it to be triggered regularly.

Instead of using Docker System Prune -a which removes all unused data, you can use


docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h" command, which will remove all unused images created more than 24 hours ago.
docker container prune --filter "until=24h" command, which will remove all stopped containers created more than 24 hours ago


Add your self-hosted agents to an environment as VM resources. Use deployment job to run the above scripts on your target machines.

Add a schedule trigger to the pipeline so that it can be triggered to clean up images and containers regularly.


Below is a sample yaml for your reference.
# YAML file in the main branch
trigger:
- none

schedules:
- cron: '0 0 * * *'
  displayName: Daily midnight build
  branches:
    include:
    - main

jobs:
- deployment: VMDeploy
  displayName: Deploy to VMs
  environment: 
    name: VMenv
    resourceType: virtualMachine
  strategy:
     runOnce:
        deploy:   
          steps:
            - task: Bash@3
              inputs:
                targetType: 'inline'
                script: |
                  docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h" -f
                  docker container prune --filter "until=24h" -f


Hi @Ziyang Liu-MSFT when I manually enter these both commands it doesn't work  docker image prune -a --filter "until=24h" -f , docker container prune --filter "until=24h" -f  just says no place to claim.

Testing these two commands, it works fine. See docker image prune and docker container prune for the detailed info.

The commands work, but they are not clearing any disk space, which is what I wanted to achieve.

Testing on my side, it indeed clears disk space, I can see message like Total reclaimed space: 3.149GB in the pipeline log. You can try to change until to a smaller value.

At the same time, you can use the original Docker System Prune -a  in the schedule triggered pipeline. Set the schedule trigger time to clean up the disk regularly according to your actual situation.

Hi,
I've found a solution for managing Docker images+ caches using Docker Garbage Collection. The script will automatically run when the disk on my build agent becomes full.

Thanks for sharing your solution! You can share your solution with more details in an answer. If it's not convenient for you, I can update it to my answer to help others who have the same question know the solution more clearly.
